# значение массива выходит за еего границы в игре game of life

Tags: c#

```
bool[,] oldfield = {{false,false, false,false,false},
                        {false, false, false,false,false},
                        {false, true, true,true,false},
                        {false, false, false,false,false},
                        {false, false, false,false,false} };

int count1 = GetNeighborsCount(oldfield, 2, 2);
Console.WriteLine(count1);
int count2 = GetNeighborsCount(oldfield, 2, 4);
Console.WriteLine(count2);
  

static int GetNeighborsCount(bool[,] field, int x, int y)

{
    int count = 0;
    for (var i = x - 1; i <= x + 1; i++)
    {
        for (var j = y - 1; j <= y + 1; j++)
        {
            if (i == x && j == y)
                continue;

            if (field[i, j] == true)
                count++;
            if (i != x && j != y)
                continue;
            if (field[i, j] == false)
            count--; 

      
        }
    }
    return count;}
```

Comment: спасибо, что предупредили

Comment: формируйте вопрос более внятно в следующий раз, а то только код, ошибка и ничего

Answer (score 1):

У вас нет проверки на границу массива, не забывайте что индекс начинается от 0, а не от 1.
Так во-втором вызове метода `GetNeighborsCount` метод получает в аргументы `y = 4` (последний по индексу координата), после же в цикле вы уже к этому `4` добавляете ещё 1 и у становится как индекс за границей массива.
Вот правильный код с проверкой на границу массива:

```
bool[,] oldfield = {{false,false, false,false,false},
                    {false, false, false,false,false},
                    {false, true, true, true,false},
                    {false, false, false,false,false},
                    {false, false, false,false,false}};

(int, int)[] relativeNeighbors = new (int, int)[8]
{
    (-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1),
    (-1, 0),          (1, 0),
    (-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1)
};

int count1 = GetNeighborsCount(oldfield, 2, 2);
Console.WriteLine(count1);
int count2 = GetNeighborsCount(oldfield, 2, 4);
Console.WriteLine(count2);

int GetNeighborsCount(bool[,] field, int x, int y)
{
    int count = 0;

    foreach ((int rx, int ry) in relativeNeighbors)
        if (IsLive(x + rx, y + ry))
            count++;

    return count;

    bool IsLive(int cx, int cy) //ceilX, ceilZ
    {
        if (cx < 0 || cy < 0 || cx >= field.GetLength(0) || cy >= field.GetLength(1))
            return false;

        return field[cx, cy];
    }

}
```